# Can Vi editior show the \n, \t, \s etc.... in a html file?

Tags: bash, vi

```
 <tr>$
                                  <td nowrap valign="top" class="table_1row"><a name="d071301" id="d071301"></a>13-Jul-2011</td>$
```

i would like to match tr>$

```
grep -c "tr>\n<td nowrap valign" test.html
```

then i also tried

```
grep -c "tr>\n\s*<td nowrap valign" test.html
```

both of them find nothing. What error here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998582/show-whitespace-characters-in-gvim

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1675688/224248

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192480/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the file in `vi`. Try `:se list`. It shows `\n` as `$` and `\t` as `^I`.

Comment: i remember one time i accidently press something and there are  ^M at the end of each line . what does it means? thanks again

Comment: @hk_student, no `^` doesn't mean space. space is represented by simple space only when you do `:se list`.

Comment: on my vi, tab chars `\t` are shown as `^I`, which I always think of as Ctrl-I, which also ascii \x009 or octal \011. @hk_student, does that help? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, you are right it's actually shown as `^I`. I edited my mistake.

Comment: one more question wait a moment

Comment: @hk_student, also, ^M (Ctrl-M) is the MS-DOS Carridge Return char. It is actually paired with ^J (Line feed), and Unix uses only LF char (^J). Good luck.

Comment: i have edit the question . Please spare a few second to help. Thanks a lot

Comment: @hk_student, I don't know how to `grep` the special characters like `\n` from outside the file. The only way I know is when you open the `vi` editor. You may have to search on internet for various `grep` commands

Comment: can i add a ^M by using sed in a html file?